# How to get user object in Ajax call

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, ajax

I want to access the currently logged in user in my Helper function using AJAX.

```
function editUser(){
    runAjax('editUser',"one");
}
function runAjax(type,regHtml){
    request = {
        'option' : 'com_ajax',
        'module' : 'user_login',
        'cmd'    : type,
        'params' : params,
        'format' : 'json'
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type   : 'POST',
        data   : request,
        success: function (response) {
```

The editUser function is set off via a onmousedown button.

This all works fine and calls the helper function.  The issue is on the helper side.

```
public static function getAjax()
{

    function setUpForm(){

        $user = JFactory::getUser();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user);
        echo "</pre>";

    }


    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $params  = $input->get('params',"",raw);

     $cmd  = $input->get('cmd');


    if($cmd == "editUser"){
        setUpForm();
    }
```

This works but isn't the recommended way of getting the user object.  It's:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$user = Factory::getUser();
```

This is the switch to use cases but this won't work with AJAX because the use won't work out of context I'd need to do something like:

```
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
```

to include extra files (I haven't tried it since it seems a mad way to go)

Is there a way around this.

Whilst I have working code I'm thinking about future proofing my code.

Update

I'm adding some cleaner code to show what doesn't work:

This doesn't work because it doesn't have the namespace context

```
class modLoginHelper

{

public static function getAjax()
    {
        use Joomla\CMS\Factory as YourNewAlias;
        user = Factory::getUser();
    }
    
}
```

This won't throw an error but doesn't work

```
class modLoginHelper

{
    use Joomla\CMS\Factory as YourNewAlias;
    
public static function getAjax()
    {
        
        user = Factory::getUser();
    }
    
}
```

So whichever way I try to follow the use Joomla ... it won't work - I have to revert to the old way of doing things.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you asking about `JFactory::getUser()` vs `Joomla\CMS\Factory::getUser()`?

Comment: Yes JFactory::getUser() works fine.  But use Joomla\CMS\Factory which is the recommended way won't work using an AJAX call

Comment: ...why won't it work exactly? `JFactory` is just an aliased namespace for `Joomla\CMS\Factory` - see the classmap - https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/classmap.php - are you getting the old "Cannot use Joomla\CMS\Factory as Factory because the name is already in use" error? If so, alias that, so something like `use \Joomla\CMS\Factory as YourNewAlias` and then `YourNewAlias::getUser()`.

Comment: using use Joomla\CMS\Factory  needs to be declared inside the global namespace which doesn't work within an AJAX context I think because the namespace doesn't exist.

Comment: Not related to your question but you should avoid declaring global functions like `setUpForm()`, especially since you already have a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When importing classes using `use` statement, it has to be outside of your class. When put inside a class, it's interpreted as a use of trait. And when used inside a method it will cause a syntax error. In your case it should be used like this:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

class ModLoginHelper
{ 
    public static function getAjax()
    {
        $user = Factory::getUser();
        // Your code here...
    }
}
```

From PHP documentation:

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Alternatively, you can use fully qualified class names in your code like this:

```
class ModLoginHelper
{ 
    public static function getAjax()
    {
        $user = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getUser();
        // Your code here...
    }
}
```